# How to create multiple GET endpoints in single Resource?

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful

I need to use several APIs in one class, something like this:

```
class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self): #/
        return send_from_directory('../frontend', "index.html")

    def get(self): #getAvg
        val = '45,64,56,7,4'
        l1=val.split(',')
        ar=np.array(l1,dtype=int)
        return Response(str(np.average(ar)))


api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/')
api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/getAvg')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add another class `Average`, then add it using `api.add_resource`

```
class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self): #/
        return send_from_directory('../frontend', "index.html")


class Average(Resource):
    def get(self): #getAvg
        val = '45,64,56,7,4'
        l1=val.split(',')
        ar=np.array(l1,dtype=int)
        return Response(str(np.average(ar)))

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/')
api.add_resource(Average, '/getAvg')
```